# Trabajar con localStorage

Tags: javascript

Pues intento almacenar en el localStorage la raza de los perros y comprobar que si una raza se repite la sume a la existente pero no consigo dar con la tecla, el contador me hace cosas raras.

No se si el problema es como realizo la búsqueda del localStorage o si eso las condiciones que introduzco en él.
Le doy vueltas a que el error ha de estar en esta linea if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key).raza) == urlCortada[4]

pero no consigo avanzar, no se si sera que estoy saturado y no veo un error simple o que también al ser un junior super novato me bloqueo.

He puesto muchos chivatos de console.log(), pero ni por esas lo encuentro.

```js
let razas = []
let cont = 0;
let contStorage = 1;
//TODO boton random y almacenar la url de la imagen
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();


    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
        .then(res => res.json())                                        //recoger los datos de la API
        .then(json => crearImg(json));


        function crearImg(url) {
            document.getElementById('perro' + cont).src = `${url.message}` 
            document.getElementById('perro').src = `${url.message}`

            let urlCortada = (url.message.split('/'));
            razas.push(urlCortada[4]);

           
           
            let exi = localStorage.length;
            // console.log(exi+'valor')

            if (exi == 0) {
                localStorage.setItem(`perro${cont}`,JSON.stringify({
                    raza: `${urlCortada[4]}`,
                    contador: `${contStorage}`
                }))
            }else {
                for(let i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {
                    let key = localStorage.key(i);
                    // let value = localStorage.getItem(key);
                    //console.log(key, value);
                    
                    //JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));

                    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`perro${cont}`)) == urlCortada[4]) {
                        console.log('REPE')
                        contStorage++
                    }else {
                        console.log('probar el else')
                        localStorage.setItem(`perro${cont}`,JSON.stringify({
                            raza: `${urlCortada[4]}`,
                            contador: `${contStorage}`
                        }))
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        
            // for(let i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {

            //     let key = localStorage.key(i);
            //     if (`${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).raza}` == urlCortada[4]) {
            //         console.log(key)
            //         contStorage++;
            //     }else {
            //         localStorage.getItem(`perro${cont}`,JSON.stringify({
            //             raza: `${urlCortada[4]}`,
            //             contador: `${contStorage}`
            //         }))
            //     }
            // }
           
         
            
        
        
        // for(let i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {
        //     let key = localStorage.key(i);
        //     // console.log(`${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).email}`);
        //    if (`${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).email}` == valorInput) {
        //     localStorage.removeItem(key)
        //     alert(`el usuario ha sido borrado`)
        //    } 
        // }

                    
                   cont++    
//    console.log(huecos)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Perros</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="cabecera">
        <h1 class="cabecera">Perracos del Infierno</h1>
    </section>
    <article id="organizador">
        <section id="img_btn">
            <div id="cont_img">
                <img src="" class="perro" id="perro">
            </div>
            <button id="btn" class="shadowBTN">RANDOM</button>
        </section>
        <main class="parent">
            <div id="hue0" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro1" class="perro0">
            </div>
            <div id="hue1" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro2" class="perro1">
            </div>
            <div id="hue2" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro3" class="perro2">
            </div>
            <div id="hue3" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro4" class="perro3">
            </div>
            <div id="hue4" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro5" class="perro4">
            </div>
            <div id="hue5" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro6" class="perro5">
            </div>
            <div id="hue6" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro7" class="perro6">
            </div>
            <div id="hue7" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro8" class="perro7">
            </div>
            <div id="hue8" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro9" class="perro8">
            </div>
            <div id="hue9" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro10" class="perro9">
            </div>
            <div id="hue10" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro11" class="perro10">
            </div>
            <div id="hue11" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro12" class="perro11">
            </div>
            <div id="hue12" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro13" class="perro12">
            </div>
            <div id="hue13" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro14" class="perro13">
            </div>
            <div id="hue14" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro15" class="perro14">
            </div>
            <div id="hue15" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro16" class="perro15">
            </div>
            <div id="hue16" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro17" class="perro16">
            </div>
            <div id="hue17" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro18" class="perro17">
            </div>
            <div id="hue18" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro19" class="perro18">
            </div>
            <div id="hue19" class="box">
                <img src="" id="perro20" class="perro19">
            </div>

        </main>
    </article>


    <script src="codigo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Debería ser `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).raza`. La sentencia `localStorage.getItem(key)` te devuelve un `string`, y un `string` no tiene la propiedad `raza`. Solo después de que parseas el `string` a objeto, es que puedes acceder a sus propiedades.

Comment: vale entonces hago esto por ejemplo.   let pe =`${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))}`; 
Es decir parseo solo key, pero como accedo a raza ahora que es un objeto....por que al mirar con console.log solo me da [objeto objeto]

Answer (score 3):

El localStorage solo puede almacenar cadenas de texto y no objetos ni arrays.
Por tanto para poder almacenar y leer items en este almacenamiento del navegador será necesario hacer uso de `JSON.parse` y `JSON.stringify`.

Para almacenar una raza

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(raza));
```

Para leer un item basandonos en el nombre de la raza o en la key dada

```
const razaObject = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key)).raza;
```